# Web API post Body object is null

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web api  method like this

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Login(ILogin request)
        {
             // do stuff 
        }
```

My Login object is

```
 public interface ILogin 
    {
        string UserName { get; set; }
        string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to call from fiddler with the following details

**url - myapi.com/login**

> Request Body
>
> ```
>   {
>     "UserName": "ingridmooney@insurity.com",
>     "Password": "adfdfdf"
>   }
> ```

I tried various combinations of request body  - but whenever i debug  - the **ILogin request** is always null. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Define a class instead of an interface for the argument or you need a CustomCreationConverter<ILogin> read https://brettedotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/web-api-and-interface-parameters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't instantiate an interface. Your webapi should expect a class that implements the ILogin interface.